# What does this error from Heroku mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I try to open an application I'm working on through heroku, I get an application error. I  went into my heroku logs, and found the following error:

"Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET gentle-samurai-8665.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-07-09T17:39:09+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET gentle-samurai-8665.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes="

I'm not sure what the error refers to or how I can go about fixing the problem that causes the error. Any help you can give would be great!

Comment: Did you look immediately before that line in the logs? The log should give you some reason as to why the application crashed.

Comment: Right before that line it said this: Process exited with status 1 State changed from starting to crashed

Comment: You need to look further up than 1 line in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has a [complete list](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes) of all its error codes. "A crashed web process or a boot timeout on the web process will present" an [H10 error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10__app_crashed). There should be additional lines in your logs from your application that give more details.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip! I just found the two additional errors that were causing the problem! I appreciate the help!